# How to parse json in php from url

Tags: php, json, api, parsing, decode

Im new to json, so i gotta ask you a maybe really simple questions.
I've tried searching around but have not found anything I can get to work.
I have called an API and received the data in json.
And now comes my problem parsing it through my php, it "will not find anything."
My code looks like this:

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept: application/vnd.travify.v1+json\r\n"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = 'http://oda.ft.dk/api/Sag?$select=titel,Sagskategori/kategori&$expand=Sagskategori';
$output = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); 

$string = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); 
$result = json_decode($string, true);

$i = -1;

foreach ($result as $data) {
    $i++;
    echo "#";
    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<b>Test 1:</b>";
    echo "<br>";
    if(!empty($result[$i]['value']['Sagskategori']['kategori'])){
        echo $result[$i]['value']['Sagskategori']['kategori'];
    }else{
        echo "Intet fundet.";
    }
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

The json code can be find here: http://oda.ft.dk/api/Sag?$select=titel,Sagskategori/kategori&$expand=Sagskategori

Can anyone of you see my fail in the code, and get me on the right way :-) ?

Comment: quick side note - you initialize `$i` to `-1` and then increment it as first thing in your `foreach` to make is `0`? That's partially logical. Why not init it as `0` and then increment as last operation in your `foreach`?

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($result)` or `print_r($result)` before you do your `foreach()` loop to see what your result variable looks like. The main thing I'd first check is that you're getting back an iterative object. I think, you're just going to get back a single object so your entire loop idea might not be the right approach.  The first value in your JSON isn't an array. *edit* I see a couple answers along these lines already.  Upvotes for those. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace

```
foreach ($result as $data) {
```

by

```
foreach ($result["value"] as $data) {
```

And now you can iterate to your value array and get all informations from $data
You don't need use $i, $data contains correct $result[$i] value

```
foreach ($result["value"] as $data) {
    echo "#";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<b>Test 1:</b>";
    echo "<br>";
    if(!empty($data['Sagskategori']['kategori'])){
        echo $data['Sagskategori']['kategori'];
    }else{
        echo "Intet fundet.";
    }
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON starts like this:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"...snip...","value":[
{
```

So the array is **inside** the `value` object.

The correct code should be:

```
 foreach ($result['value'] as $data) {
    // snip
    if(!empty($result['value'][$i]['Sagskategori']['kategori'])){
        echo $result['value'][$i]['Sagskategori']['kategori'];
    }
```

Also, inside the loop, `$result['value'][$i]['Sagskategori']['kategori'];` is strictly the same as using `$data['Sagskategori']['kategori'];`.

Comment: Thank you so much :-)! it was a big help!